# What does it mean when P value = 0.000; Rsquared = 0.012 in OLS regression results using statsmodel; but sklearn Rsquared = 0.839?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, linear-regression, statsmodels, p-value

I ran a linear regression on my data - (2 categorical and 6 numeric variables) using sci-kit learn's linear regression model and I found below results of regression.

```
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
--> 0.8399

np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
--> 149.066
```

When I run the same data using statsmodels, the results are altogether different, Rsquared has dropped crazy and p value is 0.000.

What does this mean, what is it that I am doing wrong?

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
#X = np.append(arr = np.ones((X.shape[0], 1)).astype(int), values = X, axis = 1)
X_opt = X[:, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog = y, exog = X_opt).fit()        
regressor_OLS.summary()
```

[image]

Comment: You are using `X_train`, `X_test` in sklearn and `X_opt` in `sm`. Why?

Comment: I was actually meaning to try backward elimination/ stepwise regression to verify which of the variables are more/less significant, in doing so I am using X_opt to specify a range of variables that need to a be counted for the model

Comment: It does not matter. You say that `"When I run the same data using statsmodels, the results are altogether different"`. You are using different data so getting different results. You need to show what `X_opt`, `X` and `X_train`, `X_test` are and how are they created from the original data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my error, 1st, the constant needs to be added when using statsmodels, 2nd - I am using OneHotEncoder to encode categorical feature which adds extra columns to the array depending on the number of categories the column bears. Keeping these in mind and adjusting the X_train in both libraries - sklearn & statsmodel - got me the same results from both.

thanks all for the questions which helped me solve my own problem!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot place an image in a comment, and so place it here. It seems suspicious that these coefficients have exactly the same value, this might be a clue.

[image: same values]